# Selenium Chrome driver not generating search results in headless mode

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I was doing some **scraping** task and came across this issue where, when the browser is made to run in headless mode, it does not produce search results, rather gives a blank body.

This issue is not encountered in every run, but randomly pops ups in between some runs.

Expected:
[image]

Actual (image saved by driver.save_screenshot()):
[image]

configuration of webdriver:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_argument("--proxy-server='direct://'")
options.add_argument("--proxy-bypass-list=*")
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--allow-running-insecure-content')
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
```

**While in headless mode only this issue is being faced.**

Methods already tried include:

- Implicit wait
- time.sleep()
- Browser reload

Environment: MacOS 11.5.2

Any help is appreciated